# Reading beginning of filename and creating folder with that name in java

Tags: java

i have the following files:
1006_3906_33824_Finder2.gif,
1006_3906_33824_MapE.gif,
1006_3906_33824_Summary.txt,
1007_334_33098_Finder2.gif,
1007_334_33098_MapE.gif,
1007_334_33098_Summary.txt

i need to sort files by the numbers not the last part.
The algorithm should read the string "1006_3906_33824_Finder2.gif" and make a folder with this part of the file: "1006_3906_33824" and "1007_334_33098_Finder2.gif" a folder named "1007_334_33098" etc etc.

how do i do this in Java?

Code:

```
public class Sorter {

public static void organizeIntoFolders() {
    File folder = new File("path");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println(parseFilename(listOfFiles[i].getName()));
        }
    }
}

public static String parseFilename(String filename) {
    String s = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('_') - 1);
    return s;
}

public static void makeDir(String dirname) {
    File dir = new File(dirname);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is an assignment so I won't hand you the answer BUT the algorithm should be similar to this:

1. Parse the filename (split by `_` and look for alphabetic character).
2. Strip the prefix from the location you found.
3. Use the `File` class to create the folders.

Of course you can use regex as suggested below.

EDIT: Elaborating...

```
public static String parseFilename(String filename){
 String s = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('_') - 1);
 return s;
}

public static void makeDir(String dirname){
 File dir = new File(dirname);
 if(!dir.exists())
  dir.mkdir();
}
```

Comment: It's not an assignment it's a hobby project, i'm trying to sort images i pulled from http://www.asteroidoccultation.com/2014_10/1005_1114_35938.htm and other pages like it.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful or should I elaborate?

Comment: I think you have to elaborate a bit on that.

Comment: There's an error with the substring
i'll try to post my code, it probably wont work.

Comment: Typo. change subString to substring.

Comment: now it only parses the ending of the files like: 
Finder5.gif
FinderW.gif
Map.gif
MapE.gif
Summary.txt

and it's the part in between "1006_3906_33824"_Finder2.gif in the quotations that i need as foldernames, and then move other files with the same numbers into that folder.

Comment: ooh its so close now, it still has the full pathname so it now prints "C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\data\1204_714_3360", i edited the code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

@BoinQ you can do this pretty easily using regular expression. Refer following steps

- Create a regular expression.
- Pass every file name through the expression and retrieve the number using group.
- Use retrieved value to create folder and place the file in it.

You can refer to the regular expression information [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and for java implementation [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm). Using regular expression will be the most reliable way in above case.

Comment: I never could understand regex, i haven't got the slightest idea on how do make it grab the numbers